# Can't get variable passed to view from controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Trying to pass a data array to all views, but I keep getting the error `Undefined variable: data`. Not sure what the missing piece is.

All my page specifric controllers extend the following BaseController

**BaseController**

```
<?php

...

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function theme_options() {
        // Set number of columns
        $footer_cols = DB::table('theme_settings')->where('id','=','200')->value('setting_value');
        $widget_width = 12 / $footer_cols;

        // Footer Settings
        $data = array(
            'widget_width' => $widget_width
        );

        return $data;
    }
}
```

**layouts/default.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        @include('blocks.head')
    </head>
    <body>

        @include('blocks.header')

        @yield('content')

        @include('blocks.scripts')

        @include('blocks.footer', ['data' => $data])

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: Been there, tried that, no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Occasionally, you may need to share a piece of data with all views that are rendered by your application. You may do so using the view facade's share method.

In your `AppServiceProvider` boot method add the following code

```
// Set number of columns
$footer_cols = DB::table('theme_settings')
                ->where('id', '=', '200')
                ->value('setting_value');

$widget_width = 12 / $footer_cols;

View::share('widget_width', $widget_width);
```

so that the variable `widget_width` is available to all your views.

Here is the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

P.S: Make sure to do the necessary imports like

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use DB;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return those variable to view (blade) file try the below code :

```
  class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function theme_options() {
        // Set number of columns
        $footer_cols = DB::table('theme_settings')->where('id','=','200')->value('setting_value');
        $widget_width = 12 / $footer_cols;

        // Footer Settings
        $data = array(
            'widget_width' => $widget_width
        );

        return view('your_view_name')->with($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want it to go to all views

Comment: Even when I try it with one layout, I still get the error that data is undefined

`return view('layouts.default')->with($data);`

Comment: Pretty sure `$widget_width` isn't getting assigned a value

Comment: add View::share('view_name_1', $data);

Comment: Still getting undefined

Comment: open your AppServiceProvider.php file and add this code in boot function public function boot()
    {
        View::share('key', 'value');
    }

Comment: Kindly refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#sharing-data-with-all-views for more information

Comment: Is 'key', 'value' placeholders or is that what I'm supposed to leave there?

Comment: @cvassios Kindly refer laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Answer (score 0):

Create a new provider for data sharing with views

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

   public function boot()
   {
      $footer_cols = DB::table('theme_settings')->where('id','=','200')->value('setting_value');

       return view()->composer('*',function($view){
          $view->with('pages',12 / $footer_cols);
       });

   }


   public function register()
   {

   }

}
```

Don't forget to add `ViewComposerServiceProvider` to `providers` array in `config/app.php` file

Comment: I don't want to use a bad approach haha

Comment: @cvassios Updated my answer, it's working like a charm in all my websites

Comment: Why are composers a bad approach though?